# How to create user with ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core

The following controller should create a user within the local SQL Server database, but when refreshing the `dbo.AspNetUsers` table, there are no users found. What am I missing here?

**UserController.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using backend.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace backend.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> userManager;

        public UserController(UserManager<AppUser> usrMgr)
        {
            userManager = usrMgr;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]CreateUserModel model)
        {
            AppUser user = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email
            };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Register), user);
        }
    }
}
```

Postman returns the following `201 Created` body:

```
{
    "id": "random string of characters here",
    "userName": "user@example.com",
    "normalizedUserName": null,
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "normalizedEmail": null,
    "emailConfirmed": false,
    "passwordHash": null,
    "securityStamp": null,
    "concurrencyStamp": ""random string of characters here",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "phoneNumberConfirmed": false,
    "twoFactorEnabled": false,
    "lockoutEnd": null,
    "lockoutEnabled": false,
    "accessFailedCount": 0
}
```

### Solution

After using the answer by `Volodymyr Bilyachat`, the failed `result` object passed to Postman revealed that the test password that I was using was too weak. I then knew to add the following password settings to Startup.cs, and to choose a password that would work.

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            });
```

Comment: 200 or 200+ messages mean success. 201 mean your user is created. Did you check your database? There must be an entry in AspNetUser table.

Comment: Confusing right! I checked the database as explained above, hit refresh, and even restarted Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: user possible errors: check if you are connected with the right database? Make sure you are checking AspNetUser table in the correct database. Check the dbcontext connection string. One more thing, put your code inside Try Catch block, and check if there any exception.

Comment: Can you share your string connection without credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check result

```
var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Register), user);
}
// handle bad request
```

so it can be that result contains error code.